# Elliptic approximation of a $L^2$ function

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ an open and bounded set of $\mathbb{R}^N$.
Consider $f\in L^2(\Omega)$, and $\varepsilon >0$. Let us call $u_\varepsilon$ the unique weak solution in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ of the problem

$-\varepsilon \Delta u + u = f \; \mbox{ in } \Omega,\;\; u=0 \;\; \mbox{ on }\partial \Omega.$

Prove that $u_\varepsilon$ converges to $f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, as $\varepsilon$ goes to $0$.

Can you help me with to prove this result?

So far, I have this estimates:

$\|\nabla u_\varepsilon\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq \|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\varepsilon^{-1}$ and

$\|u_\varepsilon\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq \|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$.

Comment: Please add what you have tried to solve this problem.

Comment: What is $\Omega$? Can we be sure that, e.g., $\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)$?

Answer (score 1):

This PDE is the Euler-Lagrange equation for the convex functional $$\Phi_\epsilon(u)=\int_{\Omega} \left(\epsilon |\nabla u|^2+\frac12(u-f)^2\right) \tag{1}$$
If you can find *some* function $v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ for which $\Phi_\epsilon(v)$ is small, then the solution of PDE will satisfy 
$$\frac12\int_\Omega (u_\epsilon-f)^2 \le \Phi_\epsilon (u)\le \Phi_\epsilon (v)\tag{2}$$
because the solution minimizes $\Phi_\epsilon$ in $H_0^1(\Omega)$.

The rest of solution is hidden below.

> Given $\delta>0$, let  $v$ be an element of of $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ such that $ \int_\Omega (v-f)^2<\delta$ ([smooth compactly supported functions are dense in $L^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552983/proving-that-the-smooth-compactly-supported-functions-are-dense-in-l2)). Since $\int_{\Omega} \epsilon |\nabla v|^2 \to 0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$, for all sufficiently small $\epsilon$ we have $\Phi_\epsilon(v)<\delta /2$. By (2), the latter implies $\int_\Omega (u_\epsilon-f)^2<\delta$. $\quad\Box$